# Display image in combobox column in datagrid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I'd like to have a combobox in a datagrid to show a list of actual images, instead of text.

I can make this work by manually building a combobox, but cant seem to do this via binding (which is about the only way the datagrid can be used).

I also tried a `template column,` but got the same results- listing of text showing the name of the image class. Any samples demonstrating this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nest as many templates as you need, if your `ComboBox` shows the class name just set `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` to do something with your class. Here i assume that `MyImageList` consists of `ImageSource` objects (needs some more sizing specifications):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyImageList}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Alternatively you could porbably use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` as well, just use the `CellStyle` to set up a `DataTemplate` which can display your images:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding MyImageList}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks HB. I ran out of time and just did a manual buildup, but will impl this later as time permits.

Comment: This allowed me to programmatically generate DataGridComboBoxColum's using same strategy as discussed in this question's answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379995/show-image-in-dynamically-generated-datagrid-columns-in-wpf/59390358#59390358.  The former worked best for me.